# Android OpenGL combination of SurfaceTexture (external image) and ordinary texture

Tags: android, image, opengl-es, android-camera, textures

I would like to mix camera preview `SurfaceTexture` with some overlay texture. I am using these shaders for processing:

```
private final String vss = "attribute vec2 vPosition;\n"
        + "attribute vec2 vTexCoord;\n"
        + "varying vec2 texCoord;\n"
        + "void main() {\n" 
        + "  texCoord = vTexCoord;\n"
        + "  gl_Position = vec4 ( vPosition.x, vPosition.y, 0.0, 1.0 );\n"
        + "}";

private final String fss = "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n"
        + "precision mediump float;\n"
        + "uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;\n"
        + "uniform sampler2D filterTexture;\n"
        + "varying vec2 texCoord;\n"
        + "void main() {\n"
        +"  vec4 t_camera = texture2D(sTexture,texCoord);\n"
        //+"  vec4 t_overlayer = texture2D(filterTexture, texCoord);\n" 
        //+ "  gl_FragColor = t_overlayer;\n" + "}";
        + "  gl_FragColor = t_camera;\n" + "}";
```

My goal is to mix `t_camera` and `t_overlayer`. When I show `t_camera` or `t_overlayer` separately, it works (showing camera preview or texture). But when I uncomment `t_overlayer`, then `t_camera` becomes black (somehow badly sampled). My overlayer texture is 512x512 and `CLAMPT_TO_EDGE`.
This problem occurs only for example on: Android Emulator, HTC Evo 3D.
But on SGS3, HTC One X, it works just fine.

What is wrong? Is it Evo 3D missing some extension or what?

Comment: You mentioned that it does not work on Android Emulator. Which OS version did you try? Did you try x86?

Comment: I am using x64 emulator on MacOSX 10.8.2.

Answer (score 5):

I imagine you have this problem because you are not setting the correct texture id on your code. This is a tipical error on assumptions which seem logical, but is actually not defined so on the documentation. If you check the documentation of this extension you see the following (edited) TEXT:

> Each TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES texture object **may require up to 3 texture**
>   image units for each texture unit to which it is bound. When 
>   is set to TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES **this value will be between 1 and 3**
>   (inclusive). For other valid texture targets this value will always be
>   1. Note that, when a TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES texture object is bound, the number of texture **image units required by a single texture unit may be
>   1, 2, or 3**, while for other texture objects each texture unit requires
>   exactly 1 texture image unit.

This means that at leas one additional will work, provided that you use id 0 for it. In your case:

```
GLES20.glUniform1i(sTextureHandle, 1);
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES,
        sTextureId);
```

For your 2D texture:

```
GLES20.glUniform1i(filterTextureHandle, 0);
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, filterTextureID);
```

I'm sure this will workout for you.

Comment: well, I get exactly the same problem, and GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES and the texture ID ordering things is not working at all. I guess just like other guys, this is a problem related to hardware and different phones support this differently.

Comment: It is unclear what 'id' means in 'you use id 0 for it'. I see 0 in a uniform, which is not a id but a unit. A texture id is at sTextureId and filterTextureId, and we can't set it arbitrarily.

Comment: Hi Leon, what I meant is:
sTextureId = GL_TEXTURE1 which in turns require glUniform1i(sTextureHandle, 1); for the shader. Same for 0. Not sure what you mean with " we can't set it arbitrarily." I'm just telling the shader who is GL_TEXTURE0 and GL_TEXTURE1, by using 0 and 1. Works for me.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue on my Nexus 7 and it drove me crazy. Accessing either a samplerExternalOES or a sampler2D worked totally fine, but accessing them both in the same shader gave unexpected results. Sometimes the output would be black. Sometimes the output of one of the lookup would have bad quantization artifacts. The behaviour would also vary depending on the texture unit the samplers where bound to. I did check every opengl error and validateProgram results.

Eventually, what worked was to use a separate shader to simply access the camera output and render that into a texture. Then the resulting texture can be accessed through a regular sampler2D and everything works exactly as expected. I suspect there's a bug somewhere related to samplerExternalOES.

Comment: How do you pass the camera buffer down to OpenGL then? All I could find was by going through SurfaceTexture, which forces me to use samplerExternalOES.

Comment: Idea:
i am capturing camera buffer using onPreviewFrame, buffer is in YUV21 format. Then i separate buffer into buffers - Y,U,V - YUV21 format is simple. Then i upload these buffer into GPU using textures - GL_ALPHA. In fragment shader i have 3 uniform sample2d (y,u,v). and then in fragment shader i have following conversion from YUV->RGB:

Comment: float y = texture2D(yTexture, texCoord).a;
     float u = texture2D(uTexture, texCoord).a; 
     float v = texture2D(vTexture, texCoord).a; 
     
      y=1.1643*(y-0.0625);
      u=u-0.5;
   v=v-0.5;
     
    float r=y+1.5958*v;
   float g=y-0.39173*u-0.81290*v;
   float b=y+2.017*u;

Comment: it is working pretty fast. Separation YUV21 into buffers is just memcpy (done in CPU). YUV->RGB conversion is in GPU=fast

Comment: I guess there were compatibility issue with device-specific proprietary codecs when using this approach though, since different chips produce different YUV formats.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer, but rather an elaboration of the question - maybe it will help an OpenGl ES expert to get an idea of the problem.

---

I have 3 textures used for overlay, and one external texture, used to capture output from media player. If I use only external texture, output is as expected, frames from MPlayer. The same full code works fine on Nexus4, Samsung Galaxy S3, S4, etc. (all devices use either adreno gpus, or Arm's Mali400) The difference in hardware is that Nexus 7 uses Nvidia Tegra 3 board.

---

**Edit** *(how was solved on my side)*:

Nvidia Tegra 3 requires that external texture sampler is called with a name with lowest alphabetical ordering among samplers, while Adreno 220 seem to require the reverse. Also, T3 require that external texture is sampled last. With devices using Android 4.3 and newer, these bugs may be solved. On Nvidia side, it was a bug, solved long ago but Nexus drivers were updated only later. So I had to check which gpu was present, and adapt code accordingly.

Comment: I think that 4.3 didn't solve it. That's crazy. Is this Nvidia Tegra 3 vs - any other -?

Answer (score 3):

The method on the above save lots of my time. Thank you guru:

```
GLES20.glUniform1i(sTextureHandle, 1);
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES,
    sTextureId);
```

For your 2D texture:

```
GLES20.glUniform1i(filterTextureHandle, 0);
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, filterTextureID);
```

Change the texture index is a good way to solve this.

Comment: Is this about using THE HIGHEST INT FOR THE OES texture? What do you mean by "from the above"?. Oh, sorry for the caplocks. It got automatically activated when reading "from the above". :)

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be a bug in OpenGl implementation. The same code worked fine on Samsung Note and not on nexus 4. It appears that getUniformLocation breaks on some devices for all variables that are located past samplerExternalOES.

it also appears that compiler sorts uniform variables alphabeticaly, so the solution that made it work on both devices  was  to rename your samplerExternalEoz to be zzzTexture or something.

Comment: The solution is to set it to aaaTexture on some devices (Ex: Motorola Razr)  and zzzTexture on other devices (Ex: Xperia)

Answer (score 2):

Referring to user1924406's post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14050597/3250829) on splitting up accessing a sampler2D texture and samplerExternalOES texture, this is what I had to do because the application that I am developing is reading from a file or streaming from a server instead of using the Camera that is on the device.  Using both textures in the same shader resulted in very weird colourization artifacts (the case on a Galaxy S3) or saturation and contrast issues (the case on a Nexus 4).

As such, the only way to work around the samplerExternalOES texture bug (from what I've seen so far) is to do the two shader programs: One that writes the content contained in the samplerExternalOES texture to a FBO and the other that takes the content from the FBO and writes it directly to the surface.

One thing that you need to check is that sometimes when you write to a FBO, the texture co-ordinates flip.  In my case, the V (or T or Y) co-ordinate was flipped which resulted in a mirrored image across the horizontal axis.  I had to take this into account when writing the fragment shader at the second stage.

This is a war story that I wanted to share in case there are some of you that may need to read from a file or stream from a server instead of taking directly from the Camera.

Comment: Having searched during approx one million years about how you are achieving this, allow me just drop this link. https://github.com/harism/android_instacam/blob/master/src/fi/harism/instacam/InstaCamRenderer.java

Comment: @LéonPelletier - You could have just left me a comment and asked me for the code :) BTW, thanks for that link.  It's nice to see it out there.

Comment: I'll try it at home. I just wonder how it will look like in term of FPS if applied to a video flow. I plan on having Android MediaPlayer and iOS AVFoundation sending YUV frames to a common OpenTK portable application, and use the flow mentionned above (fbo to texture) to apply shaders. That would make cross-platform video effects pretty simple.

Comment: @LéonPelletier link is dead. This is another good example based on harism's one: https://github.com/lynntech/Wide-Angle-Mobile-Basics

Comment: It only looks like the account name has change though. https://github.com/KhalidElSayed/android_instacam

Comment: But meanwhile I guess there's a lot of high level stuff that has been added in the Android Media API. Back then you had to look at the Android tests, and there was a lot of switch cases and hardcoded values for different devices.

Answer (score 2):

In order to convert an external texture (non-GPU) to a regular internal one, you have to

- First create an external texture (same as creating a regular texture, but replacing all `GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D` with `GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES`).
- Create an internal/regular texture to write to
- Wrap a `SurfaceTexture` with the external texture.
- Read the content into that external texture (if from a camera, a file, etc.)
- Override `onFrameAvailable` of that SurfaceTexture and do the conversion here, supplying both the external texture to read from, and the internal texture to write to.
- You might need to call `getTransformMatrix` for corrections in coordinates (usually flip y axis) and supply it as well. Sometimes not...

here's some example shaders:

Vertex-shdaer -

```
uniform mat4 transform; // might be needed, and might not
uniform mat4 modelview;
uniform mat4 projection;
attribute vec2 position;

varying vec2 vTexcoord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = projection * modelview * vec4(position.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
    // texture takes points in [0,1], while position is [-1,1];
    vec4 newpos = (gl_Position + 1.0) * 0.5;
    vTexcoord = (transform * newpos).xy ;
}
```

Fragment shader -

```
#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require

precision mediump float;

uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;
varying vec2 vTexcoord;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTexcoord);
}
```

Comment: Solved very weird display issues by using "getTransformMatrix". I think it must be used!

Comment: I don’t remember this anymore... but could be this depends on other factors (maybe device)

Answer (score 1):

I might have the same problem as well. after days of trying, I am proposing my solutions here. Hoping this would help others.

firstly, problem statement. just like Lukáš Jezný, I have one preview texture and one overlay texture. it works fine for nexus 4/5 and most of other types, but shows nothing on OPPO find 5, Lenovo A820, Lenovo A720.

solution:

(1)just like Lukáš Jezný, use YUV data and transforming them to RGB in the shader.

(2)multipass drawing, draw the preview texture to the framebuffer once , and read it, then draw it again to the screen.

(3)use another program before you use your own program,

```
    GLES20.glUseProgram(another one);
    GLES20.glUseProgram(your "real" program);
```

and it just works for OPPO find 5, Lenovo A820, Lenovo A720 and others. No one knows why......